# paradigm for adding/removing capabilities on objects

Tags: java

Lets assume that I am writing a handler for an event.

The event can, once created, be booked or cancelled.

So I can create an interface sort of like this

```
void book();
void cancel();
```

And if we extend it a but further we can add methods for unbooking, and uncancelling

```
void book();
void unbook();
void cancel();
void uncancel();
```

the issue now is that I can call `uncancel()` on an event that hasn't been cancelled to begin with.

of course I can just have it throw an `IllegalStateException` but I am wondering if it is possible to get an error at compile time instead of runtime.

One idea I had to solve it would be with more interfaces, sort of like this

```
Unbookable book();
Uncancellable cancel();
```

but the problem with this becomes clear when you consider that you want to be able to do something like this

```
book().cancel().uncancel().unbook()
```

as the `cancel/uncancel` methods have no idea if they are returning a base `Event` or a `Unbookable` event

So are there any clear java paradigms for solving this in a decent way?
preferable a way that also provides intellisense

Comment: I don't quite understand the distinction between all 4 methods. Why do you need `unbook`? Isn't that just `cancel`? What about `uncancel`? Isn't that just `book`? What are the states that an event can be in?

Comment: Try drawing a diagram showing all the states that an event has, then draw the possible transitions between the states. It should be clear what interfaces you need. Each state is an interface, and each transition is a method.

Comment: cancel and book are 2 separate flows that are in this case unrelated to each other (it is a simplification). i.e. in this case you can cancel something that is booked, and you can book something that is cancelled.

Comment: So an event has 4 states? 1. not booked and not cancelled 2. booked and not cancelled 3. booked and cancelled 4. not booked and cancelled. Is that correct? `cancel` can only be called on not-cancelled events, and `uncancel` can only be called on cancelled events, and the same goes for `book`?

Comment: yepp, exactly like that. For this small example it is feasible to manage it with 4 interfaces, but add one more independent boolean state and it is unmanageable with 8 different states.

Comment: I agree. Java is not supposed to be used this way. You _can_ store your states as types. I've only see people do this with 2 states, 4 is stretching it a bit. If you need 8, you could consider writing/using a code generator, or you might be doing something wrong. Remember there is nothing wrong with storing things only in fields.